# URLOpenBlockingStreamW to Memory

Tags: c++, wininet

I want to download a file to **memory**, and produce a LoadLibrary in the program process, How do I implement downloading to **memory**? Now I am outputting the contents of the file.

```
    struct ComInit
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        ComInit() : hr(::CoInitialize(nullptr)) {}
        ~ComInit() { if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) ::CoUninitialize(); }
    };

    ComInit init;

    CComPtr<IStream> pStream;

    HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStreamW(nullptr, L"http://333.cf/gw.txt", &pStream, 0, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "could not connect, hr: 0x" << std::hex << hr << std::dec << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    do
    {
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        hr = pStream->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            std::cout.write(buffer, bytesRead);
        }
    } while (SUCCEEDED(hr) && hr != S_FALSE);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that this site is in English. Perhaps you want [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: i translated my problem into English

Comment: "I want to download a file to memory, and produce a LoadLibrary in the program process" -- I don't understand that description of yours. Also, those seem to be two steps which you should better solve (and ask about) in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already downloading to memory. You are using a fixed byte array for that, which you are writing out to `std::cout`. Simply write it out to another memory buffer instead, such as `std::vector`. If you know the file size before downloading, you can presize the vector beforehand. Otherwise, just let it resize while you write to it (which is not efficient for large files).

```cpp
struct ComInit
{
    HRESULT hr;
    ComInit() : hr(::CoInitialize(nullptr)) {}
    ~ComInit() { if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) ::CoUninitialize(); }
};

ComInit init;
CComPtr<IStream> pStream;

HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStreamW(nullptr, L"http://333.cf/gw.txt", &pStream, 0, nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::cerr << "could not connect, hr: " << std::hex << std::showbase << hr << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::vector<char> kek;

STATSTG stat = {};
hr = pStream->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    kek.reserve(stat.cbSize.QuadPart);

char buffer[1024];
DWORD bytesRead;

do
{
    hr = pStream->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cerr << "could not read data, hr: " << std::hex << std::showbase << hr << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (bytesRead == 0)
        break;

    kek.insert(kek.end(), buffer, buffer + bytesRead);
}
while (true);

// use kek as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks, i made vector but i need function to find size of char. Screen: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/589894857674326037/609306752344653835/pTWCcnwtuN0.png

Comment: Don't use `vector<string>`, use `vector<char>` or `vector<BYTE>` instead. You know the number of bytes in your `buffer`, it is `bytesRead`. That is how many bytes to write into the `vector`, just like you did with `cout`. And you need to remove the check for `kek.size()` in your loop condition. Also check with `pStream->Stat()` to get the total bytes downloaded so you can reserve the `vector`'s capacity up front. I updated my answer to show these points in action.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Comment: And lastly, how to print kek completely, and not just first character? I think this is done somehow in a loop, or am I wrong? Sort of `for (int k = 0; k < bytesRead; k++)
   std::cout << kek.at(k);` 
(I want to load the dll library in this way in ram to inject [I can do it myself]).

Comment: @F1oth3r0 you are close. Use `size_t` instead of `int`, `kek.size()` instead of `bytesRead`, and `kek[i]` instead of `kek.at(k)`